# ZENOSS - Custom page with custom graphs

Tags: zenoss

In zenoss we are trying to evaluate if it is feasible to build a custom page that allows a user to graph  data such as:

requests per minute
response time
filter based on type of request, http status, os, os version.

Zenoss would read in a log file in csv format every 5 minutes with the latest snapshot of data.  Ideally the custom page would have drop-down filters for begin time, end time, request type, status, os, version that would create a very customized view into the data.

Is this possible?  I don't think zenoss is necessarily the recommended platform for this type of data representation, but can this be achieved via a custom page that we can develop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zenoss: you can read csv file every 5 minutes and parse data (you will need to develop custom parser) into rrd files; metrics (datapoints) will be requests per minute and response time - no problem.

But IMHO "filter based on type of request, http status, os, os version" is not standard feature of monitoring tool (=collect metric values and graph/alert these values). I can imagine implementation in Zenoss, but you will need to implement your own "datastore", which will be able to filter data (some kind of database with context/relations). It'll be a lot of work. It can be easier in Zenoss 5 (officially not released), because it will have OpenTSDB, but still a lot of work.

I recommend to use (evaluate) another (log) tools: e.g. logstash/splunk + grafana/kibana.

Comment: thanks for your comment.  Splunk might be an option for us and something that crossed my mind.  I might think a little more about that possibility.